# Powershell Outlook RecipientType not recognized

Tags: powershell, outlook

When running the following I get error :

> RecipientType : The term 'RecipientType' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:89
>   + ... xyz -RecipientFilter ((((RecipientType -eq 'Us ...
>   +                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (RecipientType:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity 'xyz' -RecipientFilter ((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or (((RecipientType -eq 'MailUniversalDistributionGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'MailUniversalSecurityGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'MailNonUniversalGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'DynamicDistributionGroup'))) -or (((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (ResourceMetaData -like 'ResourceType:*') -and (ResourceSearchProperties -ne $null))))) -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'GuestMailUser')) -and (-not(PrimarySmtpAddress -eq 'xyz')))
```

Any ideas?

Maybe a syntax issue I can't see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a double quote around your Filter. When you use `RecipientFilter`without quotes, `RecipientType` becomes a "cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" that you'd expect powershell to know. Since it is specific to `Set-DynamicDistributionGroup` cmdlet, you have to send it as a string to this cmdlet as a value.

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity 'xyz' -RecipientFilter "((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or (((RecipientType -eq 'MailUniversalDistributionGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'MailUniversalSecurityGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'MailNonUniversalGroup') -or (RecipientType -eq 'DynamicDistributionGroup'))) -or (((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (ResourceMetaData -like 'ResourceType:*') -and (ResourceSearchProperties -ne $null))))) -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'GuestMailUser')) -and (-not(PrimarySmtpAddress -eq 'xyz')))"
```

[See documentation and examples by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/dynamic-distribution-groups/dynamic-distribution-groups?view=exchserver-2019)